# Name of variable passed as argument

Tags: python, python-c-api

I want to do something along the lines of

```
static PyObject* printArgs(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    PyObject * oarg1 = NULL;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"O",&oarg1);
    return -- magic --
}
```

Such that calling modulename.printArgs(a) returns 'a'.

Is this possible? The best I could think of is looking through locals() for a variable that points to whatever I got in args, but if there's more than one name for the value I could get the wrong name.

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible. In no way is it guaranteed that the parameter even has a name, it could be an anonymous expression. As such, this is not a limitation of the API, it is a fundamental issue with what you are trying to achieve. Can you give some motivation for the printArgs function?

Comment: I don't mind getting a null pointer if it's anonymous.    

I'm adding an interpreter to a c++ application and I want to identify objects by their names in the python interpreter.

Comment: Then you can just assume that every parameter is anonymous (because in a way, it is) and just return a null pointer right away. :-)

Comment: Depending on what objects you want to identify, making them register themselves (through constructors, eg.) sounds like a much better plan.